# Allocation Tracker: How to use it to detect memory leaks?

Tags: android

I have two activities: A and B. Starting in A, I go to activity B. Then I call finish() on B and get back to A. Every time I repeat this process allocated memory is increased by 0.1 MB.

So I want to find out what's causing this leak. I have tried to use the allocation tracker by tracking allocated memory during the process just mentioned. Then when I press "Get Allocations" I get a long list of allocations. My question is: How do I read that list in order to find out what's causing my leak?

I have tried to solve this by releasing all resources in the onDestroy method of activity B and that helped a little bit. And also, I'm not allocating new memory in the onResume method of activity A.

Just to show that I'm using allocation tracker correctly:

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You should checkout [this video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_CruQY55HOk), it explains memory leak finding in details and is just great :)

Comment: Great link. This is a great seminar.

Comment: The video linked to (while good) doesn't even mention the allocation tracker.

Comment: @Wex For investigating memory leaks, the allocation tracker is not the right tool.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the Allocation Tracker is a log of items that have been allocated to memory (i.e. initialized).  It is not a snapshot of items currently in memory.  You need to look at the Heap for that.